# Display the current variable value while looping

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    string IDs = ID.Text;
    string[] eachIDs = Regex.Split(IDs, "\n");
    foreach (var eachID in eachIDs)
    {
        getContent(eachID);
        titleBox.Text = "Done";
    }
}
private void getContent(string value)
{
    label1.Text = value;
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

I will give 4 id's as Input say "IDNUMBER01, IDNUMBER02, IDNUMBER03, IDNUMBER04" each in a new line in Rich Text Box.

The code splits them successfully. I want to show the Value of the ID being used in the current loop in a Label Text.

Problem with my code is it shows only the last ID which goes through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the UI is only Updated after the execution of this code, since they are executing in the same thread. You will need to open a thread, run this code, and call the dispatcher (or the Control.BeginInvoke if this app is Winforms) to update the UI.

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    string IDs = ID.Text;
    new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        string[] eachIDs = Regex.Split(IDs, "\n");
        foreach (var eachID in eachIDs)
        {
            getContent(eachID);               
            titleBox.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate { titleBox.Text = "Done"; });  
        }
    }).Start();
}

private void getContent(string value)
{
    label1.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate { label1.Text = value; });        
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: but i have a problem

It shows

"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ID' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

When I try to Debug

Comment: It shows the same problem for both these lines while debugging "button1.Enabled = false;
                string IDs= ID.Text;"

Comment: Also the richTextbox gets only one DONE even if i Pass three IDs into them

Answer (score 2):

Probably your `UI` freezing and you can't see the changes.Try this, use `async/await` feature:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    string IDs = ID.Text;
    string[] eachIDs = Regex.Split(IDs, "\n");
    foreach (var eachID in eachIDs)
    {
        await getContent(eachID);
        titleBox.Text = "Done";
    }
}
private async Task getContent(string value)
{
    label1.Text = value;
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: Both yours and @Guilherme solution works. I want to know if Threading is better or the Await feature is better. Can you please suggest.

Comment: Await only works with .Net framework 4.5 (not compatible with Windows XP)

Comment: Both have almost the same performance and works almost in the same way, but Thread is manual and await is automatic (less code).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you'd be better using a timer to display your value text. You're only seeing the last ID because the loop is executing very quickly, and using Thread.Sleep within the foreach isn't going to fly.
You could use `Application.DoEvents()` before the `Thread.Sleep`, but a timer is still your better option ... imho.